# Trying to get AS3 to detect collision but get Error 1009 (Null Object)

Tags: actionscript-3, collision

I've just only began learning AS3 as I have to create a simple game for an assignment, I have two objects named obj_laser and obj_enemy1 but when I run the collision code I created, it keeps coming up with the error 1009. Here is some of the code and I know its messy.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, runGame);
function runGame(event: Event): void {
```

//Fire Laser

```
LASERALARM++;
if (LASERALARM >= 10) {
    var laser: obj_laser = new obj_laser
    var laser2: obj_laser = new obj_laser
    var flare: obj_flare = new obj_flare
    var flare2: obj_flare = new obj_flare
    laser.x = obj_spaceship.x + 12
    laser.y = obj_spaceship.y
    laser2.x = obj_spaceship.x - 12
    laser2.y = obj_spaceship.y
    addChild(laser);
    addChild(laser2);
    flare.x = obj_spaceship.x + 12
    flare.y = obj_spaceship.y
    flare2.x = obj_spaceship.x - 12
    flare2.y = obj_spaceship.y
    addChild(flare);
    addChild(flare2);
    LASERALARM = 0;
```

//Move Laser

```
    laser.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLaser);
    function moveLaser(event: Event): void {
        laser.y -= 5;
        laser2.y -= 5;
    }
}
```

//Spawn Enemies

```
ENEMYALARM++
if (ENEMYALARM >= (randomRange(100, 400))) {
    var enemy1: obj_enemy1 = new obj_enemy1
    enemy1.x = (randomRange(15, 165));
    enemy1.y = -10;
    addChild(enemy1);
    ENEMYALARM = 0;
    //Move Enemy

    enemy1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveEnemy);
    function moveEnemy(event: Event): void {
        enemy1.y += 2;
    }
if (laser.hitTestObject(enemy1)) {
    parent.removeChild(laser);
    parent.removeChild(enemy1);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Please paste complete error message next time or link to error page. People don't remember each error code. Like i have no clue what `error 1009` is if I don't check the dock and It certainly don't says "Null Object". There are many errors that can be caused by null object.2. Use debugger player - it will give you exact line number that is causing the problem. If you use Flash/Animate to compile simply hit ctrl+shift+enter instead of ctrl+enter.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are trying to do something with a variable that doesn't have a value.

Clicking on the error should take you to where it breaks down in the code. Further to that, start tracing out your variables at different points of the code to try and nail it down.

Comment: Yep! thank you, the problem was the code which said what the variable is was only running everytime the laser was shot, so for 1/6 of the time it was null.